# What should be the return value for empty `Optional` type?

Tags: java, return-value, option-type

I have a chain of methods with one method having `Optional` return type as below

```
public Optional<Employee> find(long id) {

   for (Employee employee : this.employees) {
      if (employee.getId() == id) {
         return Optional.of(employee);
      }
   }
   return Optional.empty();
}

public Employee findlById(long id) {

   return find(id);
}
```

Here the second method `findById` will have a compilation error as its own return type and the return type from `find` method are different.

Now if I check for the value and find it, I can return that object. But what should I return if `Optional` object is empty?

```
public Employee findlById(long id) {

   Optional<Employee> employee = find(id);
   if (employee.isPresent()) {
      return employee.get();
   }
   return // what??;
}
```

From the resources on the internet that I have read, you should never return `null` for an `Optional` object. So I am confused if not `null` than `what`?

Comment: `you should never return null for an Optional object` - Well, you are already unwrapping the Optional in this method, so I think this statement isn't relevant anymore. Just return `null`.

Answer (score 5):

If you were returning an `Optional` type, then you could use `Optional.empty()` like

```
return Optional<Employee>.empty();
```

But since your return type is `Employee` your choices are change the return type to `Optional<Employee>` and use the above, `return null;` **or** throw some kind of `Exception`.

Comment: I do not prefer to move the `Optional` type further up the chain and would like to resolve the condition at this layer only. The other two options `null` and `throw Exception` sounds better.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary Just trying to be complete. Those are your choices.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the contract of the method. Suppose if the id is coming from a user input - it is quite possible that you might not have an employee with that ID. It is expected that you handle the error within the program. Since using Exceptions for control flow is generally a bad practice - return either an `Optional<Employee>` or `null`.

If you expect an Employee to exist for that ID - may be the ID is passed from a list you received from another part of program - throwing an `Exception` is preferred. (In that case, I suggest a different name for the function - something like `getEmployeeDetails`.

In the end, how you handle is totally dependent on your requirement - I doubt whether there is a **good** and **single** solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its specific to your use case. The question is what should you return if you don't find an employee of a given Id. There are following choices -

1. If its okay for the caller of `findById()` to get empty in return, return empty
2. Throw an exception with some message custom to your use case

Comment: I am inclined towards the second option rather than keep cascading the return value up the chain? what will be your preferred way of handling such situation?

Comment: I agree, instead of cascading it, its better throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the full information to suggest you the specific answer you require but i can suggest 4 solutions that might fit :

1. The `findById` method should return an optional it self. this gives you the advantage to decide for each case what you should return if the value was not found.
   i would suggest to combine both of the methods to one, it should look something like this, note that this would work only if this.employees is of type `Collection`:

   ```
   public Optional<Employee> findById(long id) {
       return this.employees.stream()
           .filter(employee -> employee.getId() == id)
           .findAny();
   }
   ```
2. The `findById` method should return a default value, for example an empty employee with no values in his fields i suggest doing it like this:

   ```
   public Employee findlById(long id) {
      return find(id).orElse(new Employee());
   }
   ```
3. The `findById` method should throw an exception if the searched employee is not found, this can be done with using optional also:

   ```
   public Employee findlById(long id) {
       return find(id).orElseThrow(new RuntimeException("Cannot find required employee"));//Maybe throw your own exception
   }
   ```
4. The `findById` should return null if the searched employee is not found this can be done using `orElse` method also:

   ```
   public Employee findlById(long id) {
       return find(id).orElse(null);
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public Employee findlById(long id) { 
       Employee finalEmployee;
       Optional<Employee> employee = find(id); 
       if (employee.isPresent()) { 
          finalEmployee=employee.get(); 
       } 
       return finalEmployee; 
   }
```